# Unique Solutions w/ Probabilities

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

> Suppose you have a $2 \times 2$ matrix, $a$ that can only take the entries 1 or 2. Then, suppose you have a 2-vector $b$ that takes the values 1 or 2 as well. Looking at $Ax = b,$ the probability space has 64 elements.

What is the probability the system has a unique solution?

Alright, there's gotta be an easier way to do this than listing all possible matrices and then finding if it has a unique solution. Can someone please guide me in the right direction? I seriously have no idea.

Comment: The [invertible matrix theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#The_invertible_matrix_theorem) has listed many different necessary and sufficient conditions for what makes a square matrix invertible.  Among them, that the system $Ax=b$ has a unique solution for some $b$.

Comment: As an aside, you have not described the probability distribution at work here.  Any counting technique you could use would only be valid if we were to assume that each of the $64$ possible outcomes for $(A,b)$ are equally likely to occur, i.e. a uniform distribution.  Without such an assumption however, the probability could be anything from $0$ to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the $b$ vector is a red herring. It doesn't matter. In order for the matrix $A$ to be invertible, it's determinant must be **nonzero**. The probability that this determinant is **nonzero** is one minus the probability that it **is zero**. The determinant is
$$
\det A = A_{11}A_{22} - A_{12} A_{21}\, .
$$
There are $4^2 = 16$ possibilities for this matrix. Can you count how many lead to a zero determinant, and thus find the probability that the determinant is **not zero**?

Comment: If it has a zero determinant, there are no possible solutions?

Comment: If the determinant is zero, there is no *unique* solution. See [the invertible matrix theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#The_invertible_matrix_theorem) link from the comments above.